# Get index of an element from a NodeList

Tags: javascript

I have a simple list:

```
<ul id="list">
    <li id="item-1">1</li>
    <li id="item-2" style="display: none">2</li>
    <li id="item-3">3</li>
    <li id="item-4">4</li>
    <li id="item-5">5</li>
</ul>
```

And need to get index of a specific item disregarding hidden items.

```
var list = document.getElementById('list');
var items = list.querySelectorAll('li:not([style*="display: none"])');
```

I try to convert `NodeList` in `Array`:

```
var list_items = Array.from(items);
```

But don't known how to run something like that: `list_items.indexOf('item-3')`

https://codepen.io/marcelo-villela-gusm-o/pen/RwNEVVB?editors=1010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a function to find the `id` you need in a list you want, passing two parameters, that way you can use this function dynamically.

Based on id, inside the function just need to use `.findIndex()` that returns the index or -1 if not found.

See here:

```js
var list = document.getElementById('list');
var items = list.querySelectorAll('li:not([style*="display: none"])');
var list_items = Array.from(items);

function getIndexById(idToSearch, list){
  //ES6 arrow function syntax
  return list.findIndex(elem => elem.id == idToSearch) 
  
  //normal syntax
  //return list.findIndex(function(elem) {return elem.id == idToSearch}) 

}

console.log("found at index: ", getIndexById("item-3", list_items))
```

```html
<ul id="list">
    <li id="item-1">1</li>
    <li id="item-2" style="display: none">2</li>
    <li id="item-3">3</li>
    <li id="item-4">4</li>
    <li id="item-5">5</li>
</ul>
```

**Not exactly related to the question, but** if possible, I would suggest you to change your HTML to remove that inline style of `display: none` and change it to a class, (e.g: `class='hidden'`), it would be better for your `.querySelector` when using `:not`, for example: `li:not(.hidden)`, since any space in your inline style can break your selector. (`"display:none"` != `"display: none"`, spot the space)

Comment: Thanks for the solution and the tip. I know using class is much more simple. But unfortunelly, `display: none` is added by VueJS `v-show`.

Comment: @marcelo2605 You can use `v-if` to toggle whether it's included in the dom at all, then you only have to select the ones that are present (and can be much more performant). Or use `:class="{ hidden: checkVisible(props.row) }"` or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe like this:

```
var item = list_items.find(function(item) {
    return item.id === "item-3";
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using `:not(.hidden)` instead of "grepping" for a match on the `style` tag. Then, simply [find the index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) after casting the `NodeList` to an array.

For the Vue.js inclined, see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/634ojdq0/

```js
let items = [...document.querySelectorAll('#list li:not(.hidden)')]
let index = items.findIndex(item => item.id == 'item-4')

console.log('item-4 index in visible list is', index)
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
    <li id="item-1">1</li>
    <li id="item-2" class="hidden">2</li>
    <li id="item-3">3</li>
    <li id="item-4">4</li>
    <li id="item-5">5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use map. First you can create an object with id and value. Then use map function to create array of this object. Then you can access it with foreach, when id = 'item-3'.